# How to update record if not empty and set initial value if empty

Tags: php, mysql

How do i update a record when the post value is not empty, and it the post is empty i will set it with the default value.

**user table**

```
id   |  key  | date
-----|-------|-------------
100  | 2     | 26/03/2017
     |       |
```

**MY PHP**

```
<?php
$setKey = (isset($_POST['change_key']) ? $_POST['key'] : null);
$handler = $conn->prepare("
   UPDATE user SET key = IF(key IS NOT NULL, :key, NULL), 
   date = :date 
   WHERE id = :id
");
$handler->bindParam(':key', $setKey);
$handler->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date']);
$handler->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
?>
```

From the above example i want if `$setKey` is null the sql will update the date and other columns and set the `KEY` to the current value which is 2 from the above example.

Comment: You have error ??' what's your question  ..

Comment: did you try the ifnull mysql function ? -> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp

Comment: @scaisEdge it update the key but when the key is null it will update old saved key to empty in database

Comment: I don't understand your last comment .. what is the "old saved key to empty in database"  ..  ???  a value or is null  or not .. if is null you set the value  .. otherwise remain the same  as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$setKey = (isset($_POST['change_key']) ? $_POST['key'] : null);
$handler = $conn->prepare("
   UPDATE user SET key = IFNULL(:key, NULL), 
   date = :date 
   WHERE id = :id
");
$handler->bindParam(':key', $setKey);
$handler->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date']);
$handler->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
?>
```